# Gson error UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, gson

This is my json response that I got from my server :

```
[{
    "Address": null,
    "CreateDate": "\/Date(1507113156710+0330)\/",
    "Email": null,
    "FirstName": "sa1",
    "Id": "f3557b7f-359c-438a-99fd-da924ff9041f",
    "JobLocation": null,
    "LastName": "ss",
    "Mobile": null,
    "Sex": 0,
    "Tel": null,
    "UserName": "sa1"
}, {...
```

and this is my pojo class:

```
public class Suser implements Serializable {

private String Address;
private String CreateDate;
private String Email;
private String FirstName;
private String LastName;
private String UserName;
private String Id;
private String JobLocation;
private String Mobile;
private String Sex;
private String Tel;
```

but when I got data from my server and converted with Gson I got this error:

```
Error during class com.musers.fragment.UsersFragment$GeneratedEvaluationClass$1 definition: com.intellij.debugger.engine.evaluation.EvaluateException: Method threw 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' exception.
```

this is my code by using GSON:

```
List<Suser> susers= GsonUtil.createGson().fromJson(response,
            new TypeToken<List<Suser>>() {}.getType());
```

some fields are null and I think my problem is for that.how could I fix that?thanks

Comment: what if you use `ArrayList` instead of `List`?

Comment: Please check with data type for Sex,It should be Integer instead of String.Because of that it might throws UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: No change .I still got error @AnilGhodake

Comment: @AnilGhodake , I have changed response from server instead of null server send "" and also change data type for Sex to ini. my problem gone and code worked right. thank you dude.

Comment: Great.I think you can also handle null values with Gson using searalizedNull() method.So you can try it using that method as well.